# Ruby eager and lazy initialization

Tags: ruby, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I'm trying to write this 2 methods so that you can switch between `lazy` and `eager` easily.

For example:

```
class Foo
  lazy :bar do
    "@bar was initializated lazily"
  end

  eager :bar2 do
    "@bar2 was initializated eagerly"
  end
end

f = Foo.new
puts f.bar
  # @bar was initializated lazily
puts f.bar2
  # @bar2 was initializated eagerly
```

The `lazy` method was kind of easy. It creates a ''`getter`'' with the `attr_reader`method with that name. And initialize the variable with the evaluation of the block. **This only occurs the first time  you call the ''getter''**.

But now I have to write the `eager` method, and this is not easy at all, or at least to me. Because, this method has to force the `initialize` to eval the instructions of the `eager` blocks **AFTER** the initialization was completely finished, and I don't have an idea.

I've tried extending the `initialize` in each `eager` block, but the object it's not initializated yet, so that didn't work. Do you have any idea? Now I was thinking about extending the `new` method, so that it call another method, which has a stack of blocks to evaluate and assign properly. But I think this is a bit risky.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into the initialize method on `Foo` using [`Module#prepend`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-prepend). I don't know the implementation of your `eager` and `lazy` methods, or how they are defined on `Foo`, but maybe something along these lines would work?

```
class Foo
  prepend(Module.new do
    def initialize(*args, &block)
      super
      @@_eager_initializers.each do |eager_initializer|
        instance_variable_set(:"@#{eager_initializer.name}", eager_initializer.block.call)
      end
    end
  end)
end
```